# avoide landing page redirect in wordpress with htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am getting the following from google page speed tool

"Avoid landing page redirects.
Your page has 2 redirects. Redirects introduce additional delays before the page can be loaded.
Avoid landing page redirects for the following chain of redirected URLs."

```
http://example.com/
https://example.com/
https://www.example.com/
```

Is there any way to avoid the redirects?

i am using wordpress.  i have tried different rewrite rule but they are not working.

my htaccess right now is below

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: That's the basic `.htaccess` file you'll see after installing wordpress.  You can do a rewrite rule that directs either the first or second url if accessed directly to the third; or you can go into the backend server settings and define the redirect there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, There could be other plugins doing such redirection.

1. Please disable all plugins and try.
2. If 1 does not help, then remove all content from your htaccess file and re-save permalink option from wp-admin panel.

Hope any of the above step may help you.

Answer (score 0):

if you want try this

Edit wp-config.php
It is possible to set the site URL manually in the wp-config.php file.

Add these two lines to your wp-config.php, where "example.com" is the correct location of your site.

define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');

If you have any ssh plugin, try to stop it from redirect

Comment: why would we stop ssh from redirect. we want to run ssl only and want to run it with www only

Comment: not to stop ssh,  a ssh plugin performs redicts, I have seen this, just if you use a plugin like this try to stop redirect

Comment: OP's question has nothing to do with SSH.  OP is experiencing redirects to `HTTPS` and then again to the subdirectory `www` when a visitor visits their root domain via `HTTP`.  This is a server setting issue, not plugin related.

Comment: No, there are some ssh plugins that have a checkbox in order to perform redirection, and maybe this checking produce the problem

Answer (score -1):

rony2k6 had said to disable the plugins. This is a good idea. If you disable the plugins. Then you enable one you check if you have redirects, then you enable the next you check again, and you repeat the procedure. You are going to find which is the plugin that produce redirects. Then you are goin to ebable all , but not  the one with  the problem. You must see why it produce the problem is it a not good setting or you must use another similar plugin